# Accessing a .NET web service using a Java client

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I am trying to access a .NET web service using a Java client using:

1. netbeans 7.01
2. jaxws
3. jdk6
4. Glassfish server.

I am able to create a stub using the WSDL file which is given by the .NET web service. But I receive the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: MustUnderstand
headers:[{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}Action] are not understood
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.protocol.soap.MUTube.createMUSOAPFaultException(MUTube.java:143)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.protocol.soap.ClientMUTube.processResponse(ClientMUTube.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:597)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:546)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:531)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:428)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:211)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:124)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
at $Proxy30.helloMperks(Unknown Source)
at HTTPMain.main(HTTPMain.java:25)
```

when I access the .NET web service through Java client.

But I can access the .NET web service using a .NET web client with out any error. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: See this link: http://www.opcfoundation.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=12524. If it not helps I suggest you to generate your java client using for e.g. ANT jax-ws ws-import utility. My guess is that netbeans not generating something properly.

Answer (score 0):

After having tried different flavors of webservice client generators I finally used Apache Axis2 as a webservice classes generator for connection with MS Dynamics both 3 and 4 version (based on .Net framework).  The generator (command line based) generates a bunch of classes that I copy into my src folder of my Netbeans 6.9 project from which it is compiled, build and deployed.  From there on the major difficulties I had were :

- The authentication/authorisation part, the former was ntlm, the latter had to be configured inside MS Dynamics CRM.
- The linked entity way in constructing a soap question to MS Crm.

There's a lot of libraries to use (ear file = + 40Mb) but the thing runs fine.  I started the project on Weblogic 8 with Jdk1.4 and now it runs on Weblogic 10 with Jdk1.6.
Regards